# C++ / How can I combine 2 similar classes which inherit from other 2 similar classes

Tags: c++

I have 2 base classes: Transport1 and Transport2. They are very similar, but one of them has additional methods and the other one has additional variables.

Moreover, I have other 2 classes: Car1 and Car2, which are also similar. These classes inherit from Transport1 and Transport2:

```
class Car1 : public Transport1

class Car2 : public Transport2
```

In the end, I want to somehow merge Car1 and Car2. I don’t want to always instantiate either Car1 or Car2 and include Car1.h or Car2.h. I want to have only 1 include and instantiate only one class, but specifying somehow which implementation I want to use (version 1 or version 2).

Are there any design patterns I can use to achieve that? Or what would be the cleanest way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: possibly rethink your design - inheritance should be your last resort, not the first

Comment: If I may suggest a different design: One common `Transport` class which handles all the common things for "transports". Then one `Transport_Extra_Functions` which only contains the extra functions, and one `Transport_Extra_Variables` which have the extra variables. The "extra" classes doesn't inherit anything. Then you can use multiple inheritance to inherit the common `Transport` class, and the "extra" class you need to. That will make it much easier if you then need *both* "extra" classes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude   That strikes me as a variation of a mixin pattern.

Comment: And since C++ support multiple inheritance, I actually rather recommend you model your classes around *behavior* rather than as simple "containers" for variables and functions.

Comment: @Peter That's a good, and correct, observation. :)

Answer (score 0):

People are probably downvoting this because they feel like it's a duplicate of other stuff about virtual inheritance, but I'm not really sure how you're supposed to figure that out starting from the question you have short of just doing a huge amount of reading about C++.

I take it that Transport1 and Transport2 involve some overlapping functionality?

You need to pull out this overlapping functionality and have both Transport1 and Transport2 inherit it.  But you need to *virtually* inherit this functionality, so that a class that inherits from both Transport1 and Transport2 doesn't get two separate unrelated copies of it.

The code would look like so:

```
class TransportBase { /* ... */ };

class Transport1 : virtual public TransportBase { /* ... */ };

class Transport2 : virtual public TransportBase { /* ... */ };

class Car : public Transport1, public Transport2 { /* ... */ };
```

Depending on your actual use case there may be other ways to architect this, but there is certainly nothing inherently wrong with an architecture like the above on its face.